# What kind of Mathematica license do i need to create cdf documents for my students and put them on my (academic) page at the university?

Tags: notebooks, cdf-format, licensing

I'm an enthusiastic university teacher willing to exploit *Mathematica* for teaching purposes. I would like to know what kind of *Mathematica* license would let me:

1. create notebooks and cdf documents to distribute to students
2. and put those documents on my academic page at the university so that my students can interact with the cdfs online.

My university does not hold a license, so I'm willing to buy one but I need to be sure it will cover my needs, that's why i'm asking. I would be very grateful for any answers or suggestions on this matter.

Answer (score 7):

My reading of [this page](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/adopting-cdf/licensing-options.html) is that you are free to create and share your CDFs for as long as you are willing to license them under the [Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike License](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/us/) (FreeCDF).  This means that you'd allow anyone to do anything with your CDFs for as long as derivative works give you credit and do not change the license.

This also means that if you go with the FreeCDF option, and decide to write a book in CDF, you can't prevent people from distributing it.  If you give exams in CDF, [you can't prevent students from uploading them on "cheater's sites"](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/28206/are-there-universities-that-consider-it-academic-misconduct-for-students-to-diss).

Options other than FreeCDF may require a special license from WRI.

Comment: Since legals topics can be particularly hard to navigate in the USA I should probably state that I am not a lawyer and have zero experience with legal topics.

Comment: Just in the US? I don't think we deserve that "particularly". :-P

Answer (score 4):

Contacts:

Bradley Harden (good guy)
North American Commercial Sales Manager 
Wolfram Research
bradley_hardenATwolfram.com
(800) 965-3726 (ext 3482)

Kelvin Mischo
Academic Sales Manager 
Wolfram Research
kevin_MischoATwolfram.com
(800) 965-3726

They can give you complete information on licenses and options.

Comment: Do you have permission to post this contact information?  If not this should be removed.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - I contacted Brad directly for permission after seeing your concern and will certainly take his guidance.   Note, one can, with little effort, obtain this contact information from public sources.

Comment: Checked with Bradley. He replied, "...totaly fine to post my contact information..."